# Unable to properly compare table columns with different types

Tags: java, querydsl

I'm trying to use querydsl to build a query which joins two tables. However, a slight discrepancy between the corresponding Java class data types seems to prevent me from directly comparing the two columns values in my query. The data type within the object corresponding to table A is `java.util.UUID` while the data type of the object corresponding to table B is `String`.

I have something like the following:

```
@Table(name = "TABLE_A")
public class TableA {
    @Column(name = "uuid")
    @Type(type = "uuid-char")
    private UUID uuid;
}

@Table(name = "TABLE_B")
public class TableB {
    @Column(name = "uuid")
    private String uuid;
}

@Service
public class QueryService {
    private final JPQLQueryFactory queryFactory;

    public UUID getData(UUID input) {
        return queryFactory.select(QTableA.tableA.uuid)
            .from(QTableA.tableA)
            .innerJoin(QTableB.tableB)
                .on(QTableB.tableB.uuid.eq(QTableA.tableA.uuid.toString()))
            .where(QTableA.tableA.uuid.eq(input))
            .fetchOne();
    }
}
```

The above code does not return anything. However, the below code seems to work:

```
@Service
public class QueryService {
    private final JPQLQueryFactory queryFactory;

    public UUID getData(UUID input) {
        return queryFactory.select(QTableA.tableA.uuid)
            .from(QTableA.tableA)
            .innerJoin(QTableB.tableB)
                .on(QTableA.tableA.uuid.eq(input)
                .and(QTableB.tableB.uuid.eq(input.toString()))
            .where(QTableA.tableA.uuid.eq(input))
            .fetchOne();
    }
}
```

I don't understand why directly comparing the columns doesn't work, but comparing them to a common variable does work. Would `QTableA.tableA.uuid.toString()` not call the proper `toString()` method?

Comment: Looks like JPA is quite strict with type comparisons. If I change the fields such that they are the same type in the table definition, the comparison works. I wonder if there's a way to force the code to treat the objects as being from the same class, maybe with a class cast somehow.

Answer (score 0):

Please try:

```
.on(QTableB.tableB.uuid.toString().eq(QTableA.tableA.uuid.toString()))
```

Apply `toString` on `QTableB.tableB.uuid`

Comment: Once I call toString on QTableB.tableB.uuid, I can no longer call .eq since String does not have that method. Maybe I can do something like .on(QTableB.tableB.uuid.toString().equals(QTableA.tableA.uuid.toString())). And then turn that into an expression that I can insert into the query, but I haven't been able to get the sytax there to work

Comment: What about removing `toString` from `tableA.uuid`? `.on(QTableB.tableB.uuid.eq(QTableA.tableA.uuid))`

Comment: I get an error: Cannot resolve method 'eq(ComparablePath<UUID>)'

Answer (score 0):

It's looking like a direct comparison is not possible with the current version. Querydsl's type checking is too strict for a direct comparison to be done on these kinds of differing data types.